# Loading large amount of big textures in Unity on Mobiles

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have some big sprite animations in my project (12 animations, 60 frames of 1024x1024px textures each). Tried to load it with no special memory management on Unity 5 Personal but got my app crashed on startup on android device.
Can I load that sprites as Asset Bundles? Will it help?
Textures were compressed as ETC1. I also tried to build empty scene and it worked (no crash on startup).
It works perfectly in editor — just sprite animation on UI Image component.

Comment: Please provide more information and some tries with code in order users can help you.

Comment: Please don't use `unity` tag for questions related to Unity game engine. There's `unity3d` tag for it.

Comment: What is the cause of your crash? Did you try to reduce texture resolution for Android?

Comment: I don't know exactly cause of crash but what I figured out recently is that unity loads entire scene in memory on startup and all textures from references on gameobjects components. So I thought that i can load textures from Resources and animate my sprites programmatically instead of creating animations in Animator by using Animation component.